# How to numerically minimize system of equations composed of data and smoothness terms, ensuring minimum solution norm

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

I need to find $g$ that minimizes: $$\sum_{v=0}^n (f+g_{v_{left}}-g_{v_{right}})^2 + \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{v=0}^m (g_{v_i}-g_{v_j})^2$$ where $f$ is constant and the sums are over pair of $v$ indices; such that: $$\left\lVert g \right\rVert$$ is also minimized. Both $f$ and $g$ are vectors.

I can solve the first equation alone by converting it to matrix form: $$\left\lVert Ag-f \right\rVert^2+\left\lVert Γg \right\rVert^2 = g^T(A^TA+Γ^TΓ)g-2f^tAg+f^Tf$$ where $A$ and $Γ$ (Tikhonov's Gamma matrix) are sparse matrices containing ±1 entries to pick the correct $g_{v_{left}}$, $g_{v_{right}}$, $g_{v_i}$ and $g_{v_j}$. This equation is a quadratic form in $g$, and $A^TA+Γ^TΓ$ is very sparse, symmetric and positive semidefinite. I can minimize it with respect to $g$ with [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org)’s conjugate gradient (CG) implementation.

Since the system is under-constrained and I need the solution with minimal $g$, for now I subtract the mean: $g=g-mean(g)$. But this is not enough.

How can I solve the same equation such that the solution $g$ has minimum norm as well?

Comment: You can find a Pareto optimal $g $ by adding $\gamma \| g \|$ to your objective function and solving the resulting optimization problem.  There's a section about Pareto optimality in Boyd and Vandenberghe.

Comment: Thx @littleO! Indeed adding a new term like $γ\left\lVert g \right\rVert$ is working, but it breaks the sparsity of the initial problem, and the CG takes for ever to converge. Any suggestion how to solve the new system efficiently?

Comment: Hmm, how about adding $\gamma \| g \|^2$ to the objective instead of $\gamma \| g \|$?  (Is that what you did already?)  I think instead of $A^T A + \Gamma^T \Gamma$ you'll have $A^T A + \Gamma^T \Gamma + \gamma I$, which is still very sparse.

Comment: Your suggestion works, thanks! Finally I added the new constrains only for a part of the vector, since the gamma already links all the components. Please add your suggestion as answer so that we close this question!